# Calculating monthly salary returned NaN in React

Tags: reactjs

I am writing a code which calculate monthly net salary in react but I faced issue NaN. What is my error in this code: [image: screenshot]?

Comment: er what code are you talking about?

Comment: Can you attach your code which will help everyone to understand easily.

Comment: Please don't add images for your code - please add it to your question as text.

Comment: states do not get updated synchronously. do not use your states for calculation which are just changed by you. since they are changed by you means you know their value, use them directly in your calcultaions

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There seems to be one of the reason why you are getting NaN is because you have not initialized netSalary, grossSalary and other variables and as a result they are undefined and when you do something like undefined + 1 => you get NaN.

But why are they undefined?
You might think in your function you updated the state variables before using them, but they are not updated instantaneously not synchronously, so after you have written setTaxRates() and if you try to use the state variables at that moment the state variable have not really updated it's value, so you will end up using old value, which will be undefined in this case.

Solution?
First initialize the state variables with some default data.
then in your funciton make sure you do not use state variables just after updating them

so your updated code will look something like this.

```
const salary()=>{
   const [grossSalary,setGross] = useState(0);
   const [taxRate, setTax] =useState(0);
   const [pension, setPension] = useState(0);
   const [netSalary, setNet] = useState(0)
   const calSal =()=>{
     if(grossSalary > 600 && grossSalary<1651){
       let taxR = (grossSalary*0.1)-60;
       let penS= grossSalary*0.7
       netSal = grossSalary-taxR-pension;
       // now update all the states as required
       setTaxRate(taxR);
       setPension(penS);
       setNetSalary(netSal);
     }else{ 
       .......
      }
       .............
   }
 }
```

Comment: Also, all states except `grossSalary` are unnecessary since all other values can be computed from that single value.

Comment: Thanks You Very much Ankush Rawat for your help